# JqPlot EnhancedLegendRenderer with Mouse events

Tags: mouseevent, show-hide, jqplot, legend, legend-properties

I am using JqPlot to display some graph legends on the jqplotMouseEnter, and jqplotMouseLeave events.

Here is my code:

```
    $('#FinancialsLineGraph').bind('jqplotMouseEnter', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#FinancialsLineGraph .jqplot-table-legend').show();
    });
    $('#FinancialsLineGraph').bind('jqplotMouseLeave', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#FinancialsLineGraph .jqplot-table-legend').hide();
    });
```

With this above code, when the cursor is moved over the actual legend inside the graph, the legend 'flickers' and the user cannot use the EnhancedLegendRenderer to shown/hide the corresponding series in the plot.

How can I get this above feature working?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my JS plot code.

```
var plotCogsLineGraph = $.jqplot('FinancialsLineGraph', [[30,31,34,40,45], [34,38,31,42,38]], 
{ 
            axes:
            {
                xaxis:
                {
                      ticks: ['5','4','3','2','1']
                },
                yaxis:
                {
                    label:'%',
                    pad: 1.05,
                    ticks: ['0','15','30','45','60']
                }
            },

            width: 480, height: 270,
            legend:{show:true, location: 's', placement: 'insideGrid', renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer},
    seriesDefaults: 
    {
                rendererOptions: {smooth: true}
    },
    series:[ 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'COGS',
                    markerOptions: { size:1, style:'dimaond' }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Wages',
                    markerOptions: { size: 1, style:"dimaond" }
                }
                ]
    }
);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this one - it works fine in IE9, Chrome and FF. Can you show how the JS for how the plot is created?

Comment: @nick_w: I have added the JS code to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's actually happening here is that the `jqplotMouseLeave` event is being raised when you enter the legend, causing it to not be displayed, which then raises the `jqplotMouseEnter` (when the legend is hidden, you all of a sudden enter the plot), causing it to be shown. Because of this cycle, you get the flickering.

Try changing your `'jqplotMouseLeave` handler to this:

```
$('#FinancialsLineGraph).bind('jqplotMouseLeave', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    var top, right, bottom, left;
    var legend = $('#FinancialsLineGraph .jqplot-table-legend');    
    top = legend.offset().top;
    left = legend.offset().left;
    bottom = top + legend.height();
    right = left + legend.width();

    if (!(ev.pageX >= left && ev.pageX <= right && ev.pageY >= top && ev.pageY <= bottom)) {
        $('#chart1 .jqplot-table-legend').hide();
    }
});
```

What this does is hide the legend only if the mouse cursor location is not contained within the legend's bounding box.